# Must declare the scalar variable "@PanId"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know that this question has been asked many times and I have spend my 2 hours reading the solution on SO and other websites but couldn't solved it. So, please don't mark it as duplicate  Here is my code:-

```
dt = new DataTable();
                    dt = con.GetDataTable("select * from Panbnk_tran_t where emp_code='" + emp_code + "'", "Panbnk_tran_t");
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        string qry = "";
                        qry="insert into Panbnk_arc_t ";
                        qry +="(panid, cancel_checqe)";
                        qry += "values( @PanId, @Cancel_checqe)";
                        cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PanId", SqlDbType.Image).Value = dt.Rows[0]["panid"];
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cancel_checqe", SqlDbType.Image).Value = dt.Rows[0]["cancel_checqe"];
                        cmd = new OleDbCommand(qry, con.cnn);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
```

## EDIT:

```
using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(qry, con.cnn))
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PanId", SqlDbType.Image).Value = dt.Rows[0]["panid"];
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cancel_checqe", SqlDbType.Image).Value = dt.Rows[0]["cancel_checqe"];
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
```

I have tried this but same error again

Both the fields are image type

Comment: Well, it is good that your problem is solved. But I think you were using ms-access, which has a different query syntax for parameterized command. Please tag your questions properly next time.

Comment: No @aSharma I am using SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: Thank you @LitisqeKumar this made me clear

Comment: sorry for creating confusion here. Actually it is `OleDb `provider which does not support named parameters. That's why we need to put `?` as placeholder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dt = new DataTable();
dt = con.GetDataTable("select * from Panbnk_tran_t where emp_code='" + emp_code + "'", "Panbnk_tran_t");
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
            string qry = "";
            byte[] imgbytePan, imgbytecheque;
            imgbytePan = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["panid"];
            imgbytecheque = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["cancel_checqe"];
            qry = "insert into Panbnk_arc_t ";
            qry += "(panid, cancel_checqe)";
            qry += "values( ?, ?)";
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(qry, con.cnn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@imgPan", SqlDbType.Image).Value = imgbytePan;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@imgChq", SqlDbType.Image).Value = imgbytecheque;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

## EDIT :

If you use `sqlcommand` then there is no need to use `?` placeholders. Since `OleDbCommand` and `OdbcCommand` does not support named parameters, and use ? placeholders instead. For `SqlCommand`, it doesn't really care about the order of the parameters on your object so long as those parameters exist in the query.
For better explanation you can visit [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/231217/Parameters-SqlCommand-vs-OledbCommand-and-OdbcComm).
Hope this made you clear.

Comment: Can you please tell me that why I have to use ? instead of named parameters?

Answer (score 0):

The problem on that line;

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand(qry, con.cnn);
```

You are *re*-create an `OleDbCommand` object but it's `CommandText` *still* expects `@PanId` and `@Cancel_checqe` parameters since you try to execute it.

When you create your first `cmd` in `cmd = new OleDbCommand();` line, use that query as a parameter in it's constructor as `cmd = new OleDbCommand(qry);` and delete `cmd = new OleDbCommand(qry, con.cnn);` line.

Also in your select statement you are putting your value in your command with string concatenation. **Do not do that!** You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your database connections and commands.

```
using(var cmd = new OleDbCommand(qry, con.cnn))
{
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@PanId", SqlDbType.Image).Value = dt.Rows[0]["panid"];
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cancel_checqe", SqlDbType.Image).Value = dt.Rows[0]["cancel_checqe"];
     con.cnn.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: @ZoharPeled Oh, didn't see that. Added as well.

Comment: @LoveRajput It shouldn't. Are you _really_ sure you delete `cmd = new OleDbCommand(qry, con.cnn);` line?

Comment: yes I have copy paste your code. But same error persist. Though I have solved it using the method which was provided by @Litisqe

Comment: I have got it @SonerGönül. Thank you for your help. This was the problem of OleDbCommand and Sqlcommand which is clearly explain by "LitisqeKumar"

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `Command` object twice. Which overwrites the parameter added in previous object

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand(); // defined once
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PanId", SqlDbType.Image).Value = dt.Rows[0]["panid"];
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cancel_checqe", SqlDbType.Image).Value = dt.Rows[0]["cancel_checqe"];
cmd = new OleDbCommand(qry, con.cnn); //defined again
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Define `cmd` only once.

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand(qry, con.cnn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PanId", SqlDbType.Image).Value = dt.Rows[0]["panid"];
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Cancel_checqe", SqlDbType.Image).Value = dt.Rows[0]["cancel_checqe"];
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```